# Rotational Motion of a rod attached to a hinge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, energy-conservation

I have been trying to understand the concept behind this for days now and am seemingly puzzled by a variety of methods.

> The Problem : A rod of mass $M$ and length $L$ is attached to a hinge at one end while the other end is kept free. Initially the rod is kept horizontally and then left to drop. What will be the final angular velocity of the rod once it reached the vertical position.

Solutions(Assuming the mass is concentrated at the centre of mass):
1.First one is simple torque. Since $T=F*r=I*\alpha$.Therefore, $\alpha=\frac{F*L}{2I}$. By the equations of angular motion, $\omega^2=\alpha*\pi$(angular displacement is $\frac{\pi}{2}$ rad). $,\omega=\sqrt{\frac{mg*L*\pi}{2I}}$

2.In the second one i tried using conservation of energy, $\frac{1}{2}I*(0)^2+\frac{mgL}{2}=\frac{1}{2}I*(\alpha)^2+mg(0)$
so, $\alpha=\sqrt{\frac{mgL}{I}}$

3. And in the last one(which i was totally confused about and wasnt able to resolve any answer from it) i tried using conservation of angular momentum. According to me since the velocity and radius vector is always perpendicular, $mvrsin(\frac{\pi}{2})=const.$ and since r is always constant(L/2) therefore linear velocity will always be constant. This obviously is not true.

As you see all of them are yielding different answers and i would love an explanation regarding why these 3(or 2) are wrong and how to resolve these.

[I have just started rotational mechanics and am a bit rough on this topic so any simple answers would be really helpful. Note : This question is not a homework question!]

Comment: The mass is _not_ concentrated on the center of mass if $I>0$.

Comment: Please clarify what symbol you use for what physical quantety.

Comment: Voting to reopen. Clearly a conceptual question about the correct approach to this type of problem, not a "do my homework" question. The questioner has shown their work and explained their confusion about choosing between different approaches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concerning your first attempt: Assuming that $\alpha$ is the angular acceleration, your expression $\alpha=\frac{F \cdot L}{2I}$ is correct for the starting position only. The assumption that the mass is concentrated in the center of mass is not needed. $\alpha=\frac{F \cdot L}{2I}$ will be wrong once the rod starts moving, because $T = F \cdot r$ will be wrong. You need to use cross product of the vectors or looking at the absolute values: $T = F \cdot r \cdot \cos(\phi(t))$ with $\phi$ being the angle of the pendulum to the horizontal axis. You could ofc. use a $\sin$ and the angle to the vertical axis instead. You then need to solve $\alpha = \frac{d^2 \phi}{d t^2}=\frac{F \cdot L \cdot \cos(\phi(t))}{2I}$.

Your second attempt seems correct to me, though you use $\alpha$ now for the angular velocity instead of angular acceleration, which differs from, what you did before. Also note that you need to use the moment of inertia according to rotation around the hinge in your formula. See John Alexiou's answer for more details.

Your last attempt does not work because angular momentum is just not conserved in your system. This is because your external force, gravity, combined with your fixed point on the hinge results in an external torque applied to your system, which will change angular momentum over time. If the angular momentum was conserved and your system would consist of nothing but the rod, your rod would just rotate with constant speed around its fixed point, as you figured in your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed solution, really appreciate it. For the last attempt, could you please elaborate on why the angular momentum isn't conserved.

Comment: @StarGazer I wrote 2 sentances to elborate.

Comment: Oh ok got it , thanks for explaining!!

Answer (score 4):

To do conservation of energy you relate the initial energy (which is zero) to the final energy which has a positive kinetic energy component and a negative potential energy component.

$$ KE + PE =0 \tag{1}$$

Potential energy at the bottom is

$$PE = - m g \tfrac{\ell}{2} \tag{2} $$

You can choose to resolve the kinetic energy at the center of mass or the pivot.

- KE at the center of mass

  $$KE = \tfrac{1}{2} m v^2 + \tfrac{1}{2} I \omega^2 \tag{3} $$

  where $v = \tfrac{\ell}{2} \omega$ is the velocity of the center of mass, and $I = \tfrac{m}{12} \ell^2$ is the mass moment of inertia about the center of mass. This make the energy balance

  $$ \tfrac{\ell^2}{6} m \omega^2 - m g \tfrac{\ell}{2} = 0 \tag{4} $$

  which is to be solved for $\omega$
- KE at the pivot means that $v=0$ and $I = \tfrac{m}{12} \ell^2 + m (\tfrac{\ell}{2})^2 = \tfrac{m}{3} \ell^2$ (from the [parallel axis theorem](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/parax.html) ) which makes the kinetic energy, $KE = \tfrac{\ell^2}{6} m \omega^2$ and the energy balance

  $$ \tfrac{\ell^2}{6} m \omega^2 - m g \tfrac{\ell}{2} = 0 \tag{5} $$

  which obviously yields the same result

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! Adding to this i wanted to ask if we can take any point on the rod apart for the pivot and c.o.m. to resolve the kinetic energy. And secondly the rod has no translational energy yet it uses kinetic energy, shouldn't it have only rotational?

Comment: @StarGazer expression (3) results in the same value regaldess of where you evaluate it (the pivot, the com, or some other arbitrary point) as long as you transform the linear velocity term $v$ and the mass moment of inertia term $I$ appropriately.

Comment: @StarGazer - if the center of mass is moving then the rod has a) momentum and b) translational KE.

Comment: I'm extremely sorry for bugging you , but i have one last question, i am pretty lazy and do not want to brainstorm on this for one day.. How does the Moment of inertia change according to the point of reference(or axis). Shoudnt $I$ be 0 for hinge, $\frac{ml^2}{12}$ for com and $\frac{ml^2}{3} $for the end point of the rod which is not hinged.

Comment: @StarGazer - it is called the [parallel axis theorem](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/parax.html). At the center of mass, summing up the MMOI will yield the lowest value. Further away from the center of mass, the MMOI increases because it includes the effect of motion of the center of mass. Empirically it is easier to spin a rod about the COM than it is about its end.